# mdb-export not creating CSV file

Tags: csv, ms-access, mdbtools

When I run mdb-export, the program dumps the comma delimited table to the terminal, but does not create a csv file as far as I can tell.

Is mdb-export creating a csv file somewhere or is this dump its intended function? If the latter is the case, how would one go about getting the output into a csv file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, I ended up figuring it out. I was originally following the tutorial [here](http://nialldonegan.me/2007/03/10/converting-microsoft-access-mdb-into-csv-or-mysql-in-linux/) and was running:

`mdb-export database.mbd TABLE_NAME`, but what I needed was

`mdb-export database.mdb TABLE_NAME > output_file.csv`

Answer (score 22):

You first need to install `mdb-tools` (Ubuntu, Debian):

```
sudo apt install mdbtools
```

Then to list the tables do this:

```
mdb-tables database.mbd
```

then with the desired table

```
mdb-export database.mdb table > table.csv
```

To export all the tables try this command:

```
mdb-tables -1 database.mdb | xargs -I{} bash -c 'mdb-export database.mdb "$1" >"$1".csv' -- {}
```

Comment: Equivalent from mac terminal to export all tables in different CSV files: `mdb-tables database.mdb | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'mdb-export database.mdb "$1" >"$1".csv' -- {}`

Comment: getting error with big database read: Is a directory
Couldn't read first page.
Couldn't open database.

Comment: @karnataka sounds like a `mdb-tools` limitation

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu my file has more than 200+ tables

Answer (score 2):

I have one of the db with table name containing spaces, so from this worked where quotes need to be added around table name:

```
mdb-export Atlanta_All_Merchants..accdb 'table name with spaces' > output.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

mdb-export only dumps the contents of the file onto the screen. You need to give the '>' output redirector to save the contents onto a file.
Ex: mdb-export DATABASE TABLE_NM > extract.csv